# mouseover on dynamic table

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to make a scoreboard where when you mouseover one of the games it gives you pitching information for that game but cant seem to make the mouseover work.

Here is my scoreboard code:

```
<script>

for(i=0;i<total;i++){

document.write('<table class="border game" name="game">');
document.write('<tr>');

if(gameType == "A" || gameType == "F"){
document.write('<td name="series" class="txt12 border-bottom" colspan="5"></td>');
document.write('</tr><tr>');
}

if(gameType == "D" || gameType == "L" || gameType == "W"){
document.write('<td name="series" class="txt12" colspan="5"></td>');
document.write('</tr><tr>');
document.write('<td name="record" class="txt12 border-bottom" colspan="5"></td>');
document.write('</tr><tr>');
}

document.write('<td name="awayTeam" class="txt12"></td>');
document.write('<td name="awayScore" class="txt12 runs"></td>');
document.write('<td name="runners" class="txt12" style="width:30px;text-align:center;"></td>');
document.write('<td name="status" colspan="2" class="txt12" style="width:65px;text-align:right;"></td>');
document.write('</tr>');
document.write('<tr>');
document.write('<td name="homeTeam" class="txt12"></td>');
document.write('<td name="homeScore" class="txt12 runs"></td>');
document.write('<td name="inning" class="txt12" style="width:30px;text-align:center;"></td>');
document.write('<td name="outs" class="txt12" style="width:50px;text-align:center;"></td>');
document.write('<td name="gd" class="txt12" style="width:15px;text-align:center;"></td>');
document.write('</tr>');
document.write('</table>');

document.write("<div style='height:2px'><img src='trans.gif'></div>");
}
</script>
```

The game information is in XML form from http://gd2.mlb.com/components/game/mlb/year_2015/month_06/day_08/miniscoreboard.xml

and im looking for the information from home_probable_pitcher and home_probable_pitcher

Comment: i tried your code as it is and it worked. Can u try putting an alert inside myMouseOver() and check your code?

Comment: Works here too. What's the error message you get when it doesn't work?

Comment: There wasnt an actual error message, just wasnt showing my information at all when I moused over the different tables. When I mouseover each different game I want it to show information for that game and not for anything else, so it would change for each mouseover. Here is a link to the scoreboard I was working on http://jcampos021.angelfire.com/gameday/scoreboard.html

Comment: Could you please provide more code? There is no problem with assigning functions to events.

Comment: Is it really your intention to re-load the XML file every 1000ms? As for getting the `home_probable_pitcher` and `home_probable_pitcher` values, x is your array of game objects. So, `x[n].getElementsByTagName('home_probable_pitcher')[0]` will get you the first (only) home_prob_pitcher from the game object indexed by `n`. You can then query its attributes like you've done with the other ones. You may wish to construct a tool-tip from the information and set the table's `title` attribute for ease of display.